# How do i get an image URL for a retweeted tweet using twitter api v2

Tags: twitter

I need to get like 10 last tweets for a user with Twitter API v2.
I can get tweets, I can get tweeted image URL, and I can get retweeted tweet text, but I can't figure out how to get **retweeted** image URL.

This is what I'm doing: I get User Id, and then send request like this:

```
$"2/users/{userId}/tweets?expansions=referenced_tweets.id,attachments.media_keys&media.fields=url";
```

this gives me tweets, if there is an image attached- I get

```
"attachments": {
            "media_keys": ["3_1651583245975269378"]
```

, and can find image URL in the

```
"includes": {
    ...
    "media": [{  "url":
```

If particular tweet is a retweet I get

```
"referenced_tweets": [{  "id": "1651311444502147074"...
```

and can find that tweet in

```
"includes": {
    "tweets": [{  "text":
```

But is there a way to get image URL from a **retweeted** tweet in the same request, or do I need to get that tweet by id in a second request and have media included there?

Thank you!